# Adding facebook chat plugin in Speed dial MUI

Tags: javascript, facebook, material-ui

Facebook live chat has the feature to add in your website with a little bit code of javascript. I'm confused if I have to use it within Material UI SpeedDial component.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.